# IIS Default homepage through localhost but not IP Address

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2, bindings

I have IIS installed to run a few websites for WSUS and a few other things. After a fresh install I am trying to access the IIS page.

Using http://localhost I am able to see the page.
Using http://192.168.1.100 I cannot.

I have the firewall rule to allow port 80 through as well as checked the binding. Binding is set to:

```
Type              Port           IP Address
----              ----           ----------
http              80             192.168.1.100
```

Even when the bindings were set to default I am unable to get to it from http://ip.address or http://hostname. Default is this.

```
Type              Port           IP Address
----              ----           ----------
http              80             *
```

Is there anything I should be able to check to access my IIS main homepage?

**EDIT 1:** Computer has one active network port running IP address. 192.168.6.101 as a static DNS of 192.168.6.101.

Comment: Localhost usually maps to 127.0.0.1. You haven't included any information that suggests your machine has the IP address 192.168.1.100. Suggest you edit your question to include the output of the command "ipconfig".

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue to be that it was not listening for it's ipaddress to resolve the computer name or website by the ipaddress. Here is how I fixed it.

1. Go into command prompt.
2. Type the following commands:

> ```
> netsh
> http
> add iplisten <ipaddress>
> ```

This will make the computer listen for it's own IP address and allow you to connect to it through HTTP and Computer Name for local websites.